# Error Fetching http headers en soap php

Tags: php, soap

Tengo un WS donde intento consumir otro WS de la siguiente manera:

```
$parametros=array($valores["subdependencia"],$valores['usuario'],$valores['origen'],$valores["cveProveedor"],$valores["numOC"],$valores["rfcProveedor"],(($valores['usuario']=='PROVEEDOR')?($valores["rfcProveedor"]):($valores['usuario'])),$valores['dependenciaLogin'],$valores['subDependenciaLogin'],"",$valores["nomPdf"],$valores["nomarch"],$valores["intTamXml"],$valores["intTamPdf"],$valores["strTipoXml"],$valores["strTipoPdf"],$valores["strContenidoXml"],$valores["strContenidoPdf"]);            
$cliente=null;
$arrDatos=null;
$fault=null;
try{
    $cliente= new SoapClient(URL_WS_SOAP,array('trace' => 1,'login'=>'usuario','password' => 'pass'));//Pruebas
    $arrDatos = $cliente->__soapCall('guardaCFDI',$parametros);
}catch(SoapFault $fault){
    $errorSoapFault= "SOAPFault: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring."\n";
}
$responseHeaders = $cliente->__getLastResponseHeaders();
preg_match("/HTTP\/\d\.\d\s*\K[\d]+/", $responseHeaders,$statusHttp);

//Si hay respuesta      
if($statusHttp[0] == "200" && $fault==null){
    //Resto de codigo
}else{
    return "Error WS_DGCPI(". $fault->faultcode ."):".$fault->faultstring;
}
```

Lo he probado con un cliente que hice yo mismo, y lo he probado con SOAPUI pero siempre me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Error WS_DGCPI(HTTP):Error Fetching http headers
```

Cabe mencionar que los archivos que envío están en base64.
¿Alguien tiene idea de como arreglar este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví: En realidad el problema era que el firewall esta bloqueando las peticiones SOAP en el servidor. Una vez habilitadas el problema dejo de ocurrir.

Comment: 8/Abril/2019 Me acaba de pasar el mismo error de nuevo, pero esta vez el problema fue que el DNS se trabo. Reiniciando los DNS el problema se corrigió.

Comment: lo que comentas del firewall, es el firewall de donde está el servicio SOAP o del servidor donde esta el cliente que lo quiere consultar?. Saludos

Comment: Fue el firewall de la red, no estaba ni en la maquina cliente ni en el server. Mejor pregunta con tu administrador de red.

Comment: Aquí usan un software de Palo alto para mover esas configuraciones, lo vi cuando me hicieron esa corrección, pero no tengo idea de como funcione, no soy administrador de red.

Comment: 9/Sep/2019 Una vez mas me a ocurrido este error con una causa diferente. El error a ocurrido al enviar un archivo muy grande codificado en base64 a traves de soap. La solución fue `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);` Este error se ve a menudo cuando `default_socket_timeout` se excede el valor para la respuesta. La opcion `connection_timeout` se utiliza para definir un valor de tiempo de espera para conectarse al servicio, no para el tiempo de espera de su respuesta. Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404337/6009099

Comment: 9/Sep/2019 También aplique las opciones de compresión del mensaje soap `'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,`

Answer (score 2):

Esto se debe al **socket_timeout**, mira esta documentación [DOCUMENTACIÓN](http://web.archive.org/web/20120208093011/http://www.aidanfindlater.com/php-soap-client-giving-error-fetching-http-headers).

Puedes aumentar este valor en tu script poniendo esta línea:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);//o el valor que quieras
```

O en tu **php.ini** :

```
default_socket_timeout = 120
```