# Error fetching http headers

Tags: php7, soap, wsdl

Buenos días a todos estoy intentando hacer un llamado a un wsdl, pero aunque en la mayoría de llamados tengo una respuesta exitosa en repetidas ocasiones tengo un SoapFault que me indica lo sig. Error Fetching http headers.
Ya he intentado incrementar el timeout del socket pero el error sigue apareciendo

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);
```

Una de las posibles soluciones que he encontrado en la web era incrementar el tiempo de entrada. Pero tampoco funciono

```
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
```

Llevo ya varios días  buscando una solución concreta pero en realidad no he podido conseguir que el error desaparezca por completo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner en la pregunta el mensaje de error completo, quitando posibles datos sensibles que haya?

Comment: Claro que sí...
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in C:\wamp64\www\netsuite-sdk\src\NetSuite\NSPHPClient.php on line 348

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error Fetching http headers en soap php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106904/error-fetching-http-headers-en-soap-php)

Comment: Si el error el el mismo pero las soluciones que se plantiaron en esta publicación no funcionaron para mis llamados

Comment: Ya aplicaste también las soluciones en los comentarios de la respuesta aceptada?Como por ejemplo, permisos de red, permisos en el firewall, permisos de protocolos http, https, soap, ping, etc

Comment: Si como lo indique en la pregunta ya he aplicado varias posibles soluciones que he encontrado en la web, incluidas las que mencionas.

Comment: Tengo mis dudas debido a que los permisos permisos de red, permisos en el firewall, permisos de protocolos http, https, soap, ping. ninguno de ellos se configura en tu propio equipo.

Comment: No. No se configuran en mi equipo pero si en el servidor un windows Server 2012, donde se realizaron las configuraciones de firewall pertinentes. Como lo menciono en la descripción misma. No siempre recibo un SoapFault. Lo cual me indica que la petición es exitosa el la mayoría de los casos. Por lo que también puedo suponer que mi firewall esta bien configurado ya que de no ser así ninguna petición sería exitosa

Comment: Aunque no es la solución más idónea, sólo para probar, aumenta un poco más el tiempo: `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 6000);`  para ver si así funciona. Si funciona, de todos modos habría que buscar a qué se debe que tarde tanto. Si no funciona, convendría que revises bien el log de errores para ver si hay detalles más específicos sobre lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciona. Pero indigando un poco encontre esto en internet que aparentemente funciona, digo aparentemente porque como lo mencione la mayoria de peticiones que realizo finalizan exitosamente, y algunas lanzan el SoapFault. De momento todas las llamadas sin excepción estan terminando con exito.
[foro de netsuite profesionals](https://netsuiteprofessionals.com/answer/re-error-fetching-http-headers-5/)
Espero esto le ayude a alguien más ya que el WSDL es de la Suitetalk de netsuite. Gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Como dije antes, yo indagaría en el log de errores en busca de explicaciones más específicas sobre los errores pasados y revisaría el webservice y las posibles bases de datos, tablas, etc. Puede que haya algo mal indexado por ejemplo que ralentice las peticiones y eso terminará dando problemas tarde o temprano aunque ahora funcione.

Comment: Serviría bastante que pongas el código y el error, porque solo haz puesto una configuración.